# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion + Linux

Tags: php, linux, simplexml

PHP simplexml_load_string command is throwing error on very very large string on Linux server.  However on PC with WAMP server it works.

code:

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'handleXmlErrors'));
$this->_objSimpleXml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE); 
restore_error_handler()
```

;

error is: “PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in ...”

> ```
> versions:
>
>                          PHP             libxml
>     Linux (Red Hat)      5.4.16          2.9.1 
>     PC (WAMMP)           5.4.38          2.7.8
> ```

Is this likely an issue with Linux, versions of software or something else?

thanks

Comment: Filesize perhaps? Are your memory limits set differently on the two machines?

Comment: Is `$data` a an array?

Comment: `$data` is an array, when `simplexml_load_string` expect a string, I guess.

Comment: $data is a string.  Same code and data works on one server but not another, so I don't think it is problem of data type.